# Convert timestamps into intervals in R

Tags: r, posixct

Consider the sample data:

```
>data <- data.frame(seq(now, length.out = 100, by = "hours"))
>str(data)
 'data.frame':  100 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Time: POSIXct, format: "2015-12-22 14:20:48" "2015-12-22 15:20:48"
```

Desired output:

```
+-----+---------------------+-----+------+------+
| Row |        Time         | 8hr | 24hr | 48hr |
+-----+---------------------+-----+------+------+
|   1 | 2015-12-22 01:20:48 |   1 |    1 |    1 |
|   2 | 2015-12-22 08:20:48 |   1 |    1 |    1 |
|   3 | 2015-12-22 10:20:48 |   2 |    1 |    1 |
|   4 | 2015-12-22 15:20:48 |   2 |    1 |    1 |
|   5 | 2015-12-22 18:20:48 |   3 |    1 |    1 |
+-----+---------------------+-----+------+------+
```

Objective: To create 3 columns of each of different time intervals.
For the 8hr interval: row 1-2 is the first 8 hours.The next timestamp becomes the start for the next interval and so on.
Same logic for 24h and 48h.

Comment: You may need to use `?cut`

Comment: I haven't tried that,used sqldf no no avail.How to cut a timestamp by time interval?

Comment: cut(data$Time, breaks="24 hour"),This worked.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Posting the comments as an answer, we use `cut` with specified `breaks` and `labels` as FALSE to get the numeric index.

```
data[c('Hr8', 'Hr24', 'Hr48')] <- lapply(c('8 hour', '24 hour',
   '48 hour'), function(x) cut(data$time, breaks=x, labels=FALSE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your time vector is

```
timevec <- as.POSIXct(c("2015-12-22 1:20:48", "2015-12-22 22:1:40"))
```

You can create an start time variable and compute the differences.
Note you can specify `units = "hours" so the differences are measured in hours.

```
t0 <- as.POSIXct("2015-12-22 0:0:0")
hourdef <- as.numeric(timevec - t0, units = "hours") 
hourdef
# 1.346667 22.027778
```

Finally your 8hour variable is given by

```
ceiling(hourdef / 8) 
# 1 3
```

Note that you will need to be a bit careful around the cut-offs.  Depending on if you want the variable to be 1 or 2 when the time difference is exactly equal to 8, you may want to do something like `ceiling((hourdef + 1e-9)/8)`.